# Mysql query doesnot retrieve decimal value eventhough the column is double(11,2)

Tags: c#, datatable, double

I have a table with column say 'amount' with data type as double(11,2). every time i insert a value, the column automatically leaves two numbers after deicmal point.

```
       eg: insert into table1 (name,amount) values ('xxx','30');
       Table1
       Name      Amount
       xxx        30.00
```

But on selecting the query and placing the result in datatable , the returned value from datatable gives only 30 but not 30.00

```
        strx ="select * from table1";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strx, connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        connection.Close();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        double abc = dt.Rows[0].Field<double>("amount");
```

output: abc = 30
expected output: abc=30.00

I get the expected output only if i round the value in query itself,

```
          eg: select name , round(amount,2) from table1.
```

is rounding the only option? if so what is the purpose of assigning the column datatype as double(11,2)?

Comment: the last double dots, exists or not, are just string representation - don't bother it

Comment: Hi @Ian, I want the output with values after decimal point to be viewed by user. if i write the query as select round(amount,2) as amount from table1, then the value is 30.00. is rounding option is the only solution?

Comment: It is no matter to have only 30 inside `double` variable, the thing should mattered with just the number's string formatting representation. You can use `string expectedAmount = string.Format("{0:N2}", abc)` and it outputting same as query do (`#,##0.00` or `0.00` instead of `N2` may be used to try).